# How to get random colors without repeating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get a random color for each ,,gate".So i have 9 gates and 9 materials and 9 colors.Now i want that every gate to get a random color but the colors must not repeat.For example there can't be 2 red colors or 3 blue colors,one for each.Thanky for helping
[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dEtO.png)

Here is the code that i tryed.I have 2 trys.The old version is in the comentary

```
public Material[] material;
public Color[] colors;


public void ColorChange()
{
    colors[0] = Color.blue;
    colors[1] = Color.black;
    colors[2] = Color.red;
    colors[3] = Color.green;
    colors[4] = Color.yellow;
    colors[5] = Color.white;
    colors[6] = Color.magenta;
    colors[7] = Color.cyan;
    colors[8] = Color.grey;

    int randomcolor = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int randommaterial = Random.Range(0, material.Length);

    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];
    material[randommaterial].color = colors[randomcolor];

    /*int color1 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color2 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color3 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color4 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color5 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color6 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color7 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color8 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    int color9 = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);

    material[0].color = colors[color1];
    material[1].color = colors[color2];
    material[2].color = colors[color3];
    material[3].color = colors[color4];
    material[4].color = colors[color5];
    material[5].color = colors[color6];
    material[6].color = colors[color7];
    material[7].color = colors[color8];
    material[8].color = colors[color9];
    */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general assuming of course that `material.Length <= colors.Length` - otherwise it would be hard to fulfill the goal ;)

What you rather want to do is **shuffle** your list and assign them in "shuffled order" using [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)

It is enough to randomize one of the two arrays

```
using System.Linq;
using Random = System.Random;
...

public Material[] material;
public Color[] colors;


public void ColorChange()
{
    if(material.Length > colors.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Not enough colors to have a unique color for each material!", this);
        return;
    }

    colors = new [] {
        Color.blue, 
        Color.black, 
        Color.red, 
        Color.green, 
        Color.yellow, 
        Color.white, 
        Color.magenta, 
        Color.cyan, 
        Color.grey };

    var rnd = new Random();
    var randomColors = colors.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();  

    for(var i = 0; i < material.Length; i++)
    {
        material[i].color = randomColors[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, to use rnd.Next(), your Random class should be the System.Random class, not the UnityEngine.Random one.

Comment: @Lotan you are right, at first there was an error then i read your note and it worked