# How to assign random colors in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to spawn 5 gameobjects with a random color, but i don't want the colors to repeat.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
void RandomColor()
{
    colors = new[] {
    Color.blue,
    Color.magenta,
    Color.red,
    Color.green,
    Color.yellow};

    int rand = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i <= colors.Length; i++)
    {
        PickUp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[rand];

    }
}
```

Comment: Would this answer your question? [How to get random colors without repeating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999806/i-want-to-know-how-to-get-a-random-color-in-unity/61999890#61999890)

Answer (score 3):

One way of achieving this would be to shuffle the array of colors, and then access them normally.

---

**Example**

Here's a helper function to shuffle an array.

```
public static void Shuffle(Color[] array)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = array.Length-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j = rand.Next(0, i+1);
        Color temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Here's how you can use this:

```
colors = ...;

Shuffle(colors);

for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
{
    ... = colors[i];
}
```

This uses the [Durstenfeld version of the Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) for O(N) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest two options. The first being that you **remove the item from the array after you have assigned it**, to make sure there are no repeats. To do this you will need to make colors a list instead, so you can remove elements. 
If you want to spawn 5 gameObjects with different colors, but don't want repeats, then you will need to assign some variables outside of the function, or do the colors for all the gameobjects in the same function. In the following example, **one function is used to assign a random color to all the different gameObjects**.

```
void RandomColor()
{
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>(); // make this list contain the colors you want

    while (colors.Count > 0) // will do the following code 5 times if you assign 5 colors to 5 new game objects
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(0, colors.Length); // get a random color from the lists
        GameObject pickUp = Instantiate (PICKUPGAMEOBJECT, WHERE YOU WANT TO SPAWN IT, Quaternion.identity); // Instantiate/spawn your pickup here
        pickUp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[rand]; // assign the gameObject a random color from the list
        colors.Remove (colors[rand]); // remove the item from the list so it can't be called again
    }
}
```

The other way would be to have **another array and add all the colors you have used there**. Just like the other example, you will need to use **one function to assign a random color to all the different gameObjects**.

```
void RandomColor()
{
    Color[] colors = {
    Color.blue,
    Color.magenta,
    Color.red,
    Color.green,
    Color.yellow};
    List<Color> usedColors = new List<Color>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i <= colors.Length; i++)
    {
        bool foundNewColor = false; 
        while (!foundNewColor)
        {
            int rand = Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
            if (!usedColors.Contains(colors[rand])
                foundNewColor = true; 
        }
        GameObject pickUp = Instantiate (PICKUPGAMEOBJECT, WHERE YOU WANT TO SPAWN IT, Quaternion.identity); // Instantiate/spawn your pickup here
        pickUp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colors[rand]; // assign the gameObject a random color from the list
        usedColors.Add (color[rand]); 
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but the logic is there.